# "Agree to all" in French

Tags: traduction, pronoms

I am translating a web interface to French. The button says "Agree to All" confirming the user agrees to all the conditions stated above. What is the best translation in French for this button?

> Tout accepter

or

> Accepter toutes

Comment: If there's no way to accept conditions 1 & 3 and disagree with condition 2, then from a UX perspective it seems to me "Accept" or "Agree" would be the correct caption to use in English, making "Accepter" a fine translation - and rather commonly seen everywhere, too.

Comment: "Agree to all" is already very bad English - you would expect anything like that to say "Agree to all terms" or "Agree to all rules" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> J'accepte **tout** (par example) ce que tu as proposé.
>
> I accept everything (for example) that you have proposed.

***Tout** est un adjectif indéfini, précédant et déterminant ici le pronom démonstratif neutre **ce**, lui-même antécédent du pronom relatif **que**.*

(**Tout** is an indefinite adjective, preceding and determining here the neutral demonstrative pronoun ***ce***, itself antecedent of the relative pronoun ***que***.)

---

> J'accepte **tout**.

***Tout** est ici un adverbe signifiant* everything.

(**Tout** is an adverb here, meaning everything.)

**Tout accepter** pourrait traduire en français agree to all/accept everything.

(**Tout accepter** could be interpreted in French as agree to all/accept everything.)

See for instance

[linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/tout+accepter.html)

*Il est encore un adverbe.*

---

> *Accepter **toutes** les conditions/les règles/les modifications.*
>
> Accept
> all the conditions / rules / changes.

***Toutes** est ici le féminin singulier de l'adjectif tout (tout/tous/toute/toutes). Un adjectif doit s'ajouter à un nom ou à un pronom auquel il apporte une précision. La structure **accepter toutes** n'est donc pas possible.*

(Here **toute** is the singular feminine of the adjective **tout**. An adjective must be related to a name or a pronoun which it describes. Thus, the form *accepter toutes* is not allowed.)

Answer (score 20):

You can say either :

> Tout accepter

Or

> Accepter toutes les conditions

But you can't say `accepter toutes` without anything behind. (Or at least never seen it)

Comment: *Les accepter toutes* is possible though.

Answer (score -6):

It would be *accepter toutes* since the user is going to *accepter toutes les conditions*

Comment: As a French, I disagree, *accepter toutes* does sound weird without something after "toutes". I prefer guillau4's answer

Comment: Any native speaker would ask "accepter toutes quoi" ? You need to add a noun after toutes.

Comment: *Tout* is an adverb and can be used before or after the verb without anything else. *Accepter tout* is then possible. *Toutes* is an adjective so it requires a noun.